# Merge data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that tracks history of customer location by period. It looks like this:

```
CusID   Location  Period
1       SYD       201501
1       MEL       201504
1       SYD       201506
```

I have a `Period` table with a list of all periods. Is there any way to select data from these two tables so I see this result:

```
CusID   Location  Period
1       SYD       201501
1       SYD       201502
1       SYD       201503
1       MEL       201504
1       MEL       201504
1       SYD       201506
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can edit your question to add this information, as well as the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only SQL Server supported the `ignore nulls` option on `lag()`:

```
select cl.cusid, p.period,
       lag(cl.location ignore nulls) over (partition by cusid order by period)
from period p cross join
     customerlocation cl
     on cl.period = p.period;
```

But, it doesn't.  One method uses `outer apply:

```
select c.cusid, p.period, cl.location
from period p cross join
     (select distinct cusid from customerlocation) c outer apply
     (select top 1 cl.*
      from customerlocation cl
      where cl.period <= p.period and cl.cusid = c.cusid
      order by cl.period desc
     ) cl;
```

If you have a table of customers, then you can use that instead of the second subquery (for `c`).